# How to net a dataset?

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset:

```
data have;
format id1 id2 $25. value 8.;
input id1 id2 value;
datalines;
a   b   10
a   c   2
a   d   6
b   a   5
c   a   3
c   d   7
;
run;
```

and I would like to get the following one:

```
data want;
format id1 id2 $25. value 8.;
input id1 id2 value;
datalines;
a   b   5
a   d   6
c   a   1
c   d   7
;
run;
```

In practice I have
- looked for non ordered couples across the first two rows,
- kept the couple such that the value is bigger,
- and assigned it the difference between values.

The order of the observations is not relevant, but the order of IDs is fundamental (for example the observation (c   a   1) in the final dataset is not equivalent to (c   a   1), but to (c   a   -1) ).
For simplicity I used the letters, but IDs can be any string ($25.).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Sort id1/id2 alphabetically, and if that involves swapping them, set `value` to `value*-1`. Then sort `by id1 id2`.  Then sum the rows as needed to get 1 per id1/id2 combination.  Then swap back as needed.

```
data have;
format id1 id2 $25. value 8.;
input id1 id2 value;
datalines;
a   b   10
a   c   2
a   d   6
b   a   5
c   a   3
c   d   7
;
run;

data reversed;
  set have;
  if id1 < id2 then do;
    value = value * -1;
    _id1 = id1;
    id1  = id2;
    id2  = _id1;
  end;
  drop _:;
run;

proc sort data=reversed;
  by id1 id2;
run;

data want;
  set reversed;
  by id1 id2;
  if first.id2 then _value=0;
  _value + value;
  if last.id2 then do;
    value = _value;
    if value < 0 then do;
      _id1 = id1;
      id1  = id2;
      id2  = _id1;
      value = value * -1;
    end;
    output;
  end;
  drop _:;
run;
```